# SQL Query: Rows to Columns Pivot into PHP Array / HTML Output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

thanks for all your help in Advance.

I have a table called 'data' in MySQL PHPmyAdmin, like this;

```
Primary | Date| User | Response
   1      Mon   Tom      Yes
   2      Mon   Terry    No
   3      Mon   Lucas    Yes
   4      Tue   Tom      No
   5      Tue   Terry    No
   6      Tue   Lucas    Yes
   7      Wed   Tom      Yes
   8      Wed   Terry    Yes
   9      Wed   Lucas    No
```

How do i output into a table, via most probably SQL query or Pivot / php arrays, into this ready for HTML table output;

```
Date | Tom | Terry | Lucas
Mon    Yes   No      Yes
Tue    No    No      Yes
Wed    Yes   Yes     No
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN user = 'Tom' THEN Response ELSE NULL END) Tom,
        MAX(CASE WHEN user = 'Terry' THEN Response ELSE NULL END) Terry ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN user = 'Lucas' THEN Response ELSE NULL END) Lucas
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5321/1)

if you have unknown number of `days`, a dynamic sql is more preferred,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when user = ''',
      user,
      ''' then Response end) AS ',
      user
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  Date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM    tableName
                  GROUP   BY Date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5321/4)